# How do I get all the fields of account using a custom apex webservice?

Tags: apex, webservices

I'm trying to extract all the fields of an Account using a custom Apex webservice. As a first step, I wrote some sample code:

```
global class testweb{
    webservice static Account getAccount(){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    }
}
```

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: schemaMap at line 7 column 45

...

> Update

```
global class AccountExtract{ 
   webservice static Account getallfieldsofaccount() { 
     Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
     Map<String,  Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap 
                   =gd.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
     system.debug('object map'+gd); 
     system.debug('field map'+fieldMap); 
     return Account; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap =gd.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap(); 

 system.debug('object map'+gd);
 system.debug('field map'+fieldMap);
```

Comment: Do orgs still blow up after 100 getGlobalDescribes in a 24-hour period?

Comment: In a single transaction if 100 getGlobalDescribes i have seen governor limit being hit not sure on this org limit for 24 hours

Comment: i tried the same. here is the error that i get:: Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement. at line 10 column 2

Comment: put your whole code your return type should be Map and if void then you should not return anything

Comment: @Mohit   do i need to add return Account:?????

Comment: global class AccountExtract{
webservice static Account getallfieldsofaccount()
{
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap =gd.get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap(); 

 system.debug('object map'+gd);
 system.debug('field map'+fieldMap);
return Account;
 }}

Comment: @user4902 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>
1) Change "webservice static Account getallfieldsofaccount()" to "webservice static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> getallfieldsofaccount()"

2) Change "return Account" to "return fieldMap".

Also you can further refine (reduce load) your response by changing that Map to list of Field names or list of API names using getdescribe() method of Schema.DescribeFieldResult

Comment: Old write up on this but still works. http://corycowgill.blogspot.com/2011/01/building-dynamic-soql-select-all-query.html

Comment: Pretty sure describe is no longer a governor limit. And it wasn't all describe calls...just certain ones.

Comment: No governor limits on describe callouts present anymore

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use all fields of Account to perform some query. You can do something like this:

```
global class AccountExtract { 
    webservice static List<String> getallfieldsofaccount() {
        List<String> Fields = new List<String>();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().Fields.getMap(); 
        for ( Schema.SObjectField ft : fMap.values() ) {
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fd = ft.getDescribe(); 
            if ( fd.isCreateable() ){ 
                Fields.add(fd.getName());
            }
        }
        return Fields;
    }
}
```

You can then use this List of fields to create your query string.